# Getting while training RNN on TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tpu

I get this error while using TPU while training my simple RNN model.

```
  (0) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_245]]
  (1) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_197]]
  (2) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_233]]
  (3) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_173]]
  (4) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_257]]
  (5) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_221]]
  (6) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_185]]
  (7) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/dynamic_dimension_inference.cc:1343) operand != nullptr 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_15240937476258052108/_5/_209]]
  (8) Internal: {{function_node __inference_train_function_4697}} Compilation failure: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/tensorflow/ ... [truncated]
```

### This is the code for initializing TPU

```
try:
  # TPU detection. No parameters necessary if TPU_NAME environment variable is
  # set: this is always the case on Kaggle.
  #tpu = None
  resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
  tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
  print('Running on TPU ', resolver.master())
except ValueError:
  resolver = None

if resolver:
  tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
  tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
  print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
  strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
else:
  # Default distribution strategy in Tensorflow. Works on CPU and single GPU.
  strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()

 print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
```

### This is the model, I was training :

```
with strategy.scope():
  # A simpleRNN without any pretrained embeddings and one dense layer
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(
    Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
    300,
    input_length=max_len)
  )
  model.add(SimpleRNN(100))
  model.add(Dense(no_of_categories, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
  )
```

model.summary()

Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trying setting the `unroll` parameter of the `SimpleRNN` layer to `True`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():
  vocab_size = 100
  max_len = 20
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size + 1,300, input_length=max_len))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(100, unroll=True))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

x = tf.random.uniform((50, max_len), maxval=vocab_size, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.random.uniform((50, 1), maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=10)
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=5, epochs=5)
```

Also, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63568412/rnn-on-colab-tpu-runs-at-the-same-speed-as-local-cpu-version) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190684/why-tf-nn-bidirectional-dynamic-rnn-has-a-incompatible-operations-on-tpu-whe).

Comment: I have one question, Can you explain why RNN is dynamic? Is it because it takes different lengths of sequences?

Comment: Yes, it is referring to variable length sequences.

Comment: But for long sequences, It won't work! It took so much time to build model, any solution for that?

Comment: I would recommend reading about the possibilities and limitations of training with a TPU here https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/faq?hl=en.